# systemd permission issue with user root

Tags: permissions, systemd, setuid

I'm trying to setup hylafax+ in fedora, either with the rpm file or by source code. hylafax+ is not prepared for systemd, so I wrote i.a. the following file "/etc/systemd/system/hylafax-faxgetty-ttyACM0.service", which works fine in ubuntu and Opensuse:

```
[Unit]
Description=HylaFAX faxgetty for ttyACM0, ...

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
Restart=always
RestartSec=30
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/faxgetty ttyACM0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but gives me the error "**Can not setup permissions (uid)**" in fedora.
When I run the code:

```
/usr/sbin/faxgetty -D ttyACM0
```

manually as root, it seems to run (the process persists).

I found the single location where the error message is produced in the source code of hylafax+ and modified it slightly to be more informative, like this:

```
faxApp::setupPermissions(void)
{
    if (getuid() != 0)
        faxApp::fatal("The fax server must run with real uid root.\n");
    uid_t euid = geteuid();
    const passwd* pwd = getpwnam(FAX_USER);
    if (!pwd)
        faxApp::fatal("No fax user \"%s\" defined on your system!\n"
            "This software is not installed properly!", FAX_USER);
    if (euid == 0) {
        if (initgroups(pwd->pw_name, pwd->pw_gid) != 0)
            faxApp::fatal("Can not setup permissions (supplementary groups)");
        if (setegid(pwd->pw_gid) < 0)
            faxApp::fatal("Can not setup permissions (gid)");
        if (seteuid(pwd->pw_uid) < 0) {
            char buf[50];
            sprintf(buf,"Perm.for %s %d euid: %d",FAX_USER, pwd->pw_uid, euid);
//          faxApp::fatal("Can not setup permissions (uid)");
            faxApp::fatal(buf);
        }
```

Now it gives me:

```
FaxGetty[6359]: Perm.for uucp 10 euid: 0
```

The respective entries of my password files:
/etc/passwd:

```
uucp:x:10:10:Facsimile Agent:/var/spool/hylafax:/bin/bash
```

/etc/group:

```
uucp:x:10:uucp
```

Can anybody tell me what might be going wrong?

Comment: [seteuid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seteuid.2.html) sets the [errno](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503878/how-to-know-what-the-errno-means), print it out to see what it is actually complaining about.

Comment: Thank You: It gave me: errno: 1, strerror(errno): "Operation not permitted"

Comment: Hmm, root not having access to do something is weird. Do you happen to run selinux? or apparmour?

Comment: Wow! I don't know anything about selinux so far but after googling it, disabling it in /etc/selinux/config and rebooting, my faxgetty service works! Thank You!

Comment: so far, I couldn't find out which configuration within selinux might allow to run selinux and faxgetty simultaneously: 
- in former discussions, the boolean "httpd_disable_trans" was mentioned but no longer seems to exist,
- turning on all 305 existing booleans did not help,
- with SELINUX=permissive, /var/log/messages contains: 
'audit: AVC avc:  denied  { setuid } for  pid=1842 comm="faxgetty" capability=7  scontext=system_u:system_r:getty_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:system_r:getty_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=capability permissive=1'
which is too high for me to take as hint

Comment: First, never disable selinux; if you must set it to permissive. Disabling it means it wont update any rules and will make it hard to reenable it in the future if you need to. Permissive means it wont enforce any of the rules but it will still update them (for example during system upgrade).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From you output it looks like the following is happening:

- Your application is running as root.
- It is able to change groups to a lower privileged group
- It is attempting to switch to a lower privileged user but failing.

First, [seteuid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seteuid.2.html) like allot of syscalls sets the [errno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503878/how-to-know-what-the-errno-means) which will tell you the actual error. It is best to print this out as part of your error message to get the actual reason for failure.

However, it is most likely a permission error. Permission errors as far as you can tell they have permission to do the action (which is weird as root since they should be able to do anything) is an indication that selinux (or similar service like apparmour) is at work. They are the only services I know of that can block the root user from some action.

The quickest way to tell if selinux is at fault (I am not that familiar with apparmour) is to check if it is on (ie "enforcing")

```
sestatus
```

and then checking for avc denials in the audit log

```
sudo grep avc /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

If this returns anything then selinux is blocking something. You can further prove it is selinux by temporarily setting ti to permissive with the following

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

If you are now able to do what you require then it is definitely selinux. You have two options now; [permanently set selinux to permissive](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-430e52f7f8a7b41ad5fc42a2f95d3e495d13d348) lowering the security of your system (discouraged) or [generating the rules required by your application](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-faa96b3fdd922004cdb988c1989e56191c257c01).

Comment: Also Your Link to generating selinux rules worked perfectly! Thank You (I happen not to be able to upvote Your answer in lack of own credits)!

Answer (score 0):

You should leave the `User=root` and `Group=root` out of your service file. These are unnecessary for processes that are started as a system service (they start as root already) and are likely causing your process to have problems changing to another euid.

Comment: This is not the issue, from the output he has given you can see that the program already has root permissions; it is having trouble switching to a non root user.

Comment: In fact, leaving them out did not help.